How to solve dependency problem? "Could not find tyrantgit:explosionfield:1.0.1. Required by: project :app"
I was using implementation 'tyrantgit:explosionfield:1.0.1' for animation effects. Now after updating to latest versions android studio is issuing following error:
Could not find tyrantgit:explosionfield:1.0.1. Required by:     project :app

Is there any way to solve this issue? Thanks.

I solved this problem by downloading and copying the folder containing codes of tyrantgit. 
It worked like a charm after i copied the tyrantgit folder under my projects java folder.
